# Could NOT find PythonInterp for QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, python-3

I'm trying to build Qgis on windows, and I'm following the instructions provided by Qgis, but I've had problems with the python interpreter already being in cmake-gui.
I think the following error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138
>   (message): Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version
>   "1.4", but required is at least "3" (found
>   C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/python3.exe) Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:151
>   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:640 (FIND_PACKAGE)

I have been reading and says that it might have other versions installed,
I have uninstalled all versions of python.
But I still see the same, error,
Verify that my executable was not damaged, it is not.

I'm installing everything on the 64-bit version, on a windows 10 machine,
Visual studio 2015, Qt5, and python 3.6

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: QGIS 2.18 does run with python 2.7.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to check your PATH settings.